# Which of the following sets is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under the usual operations of addition and scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$1)$ the set of all points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x=-z$ and $x=z$

$2)$ the set of all points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\frac{x-1}{2}= \frac{y+2}{3} = \frac{z}{4}$

$3)$ the set of all points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x+y+z=0$ and $x-y+z=1$

$$$$
I know that in order to be a subspace, it needs to fulfill the following: contain the zero vector, be closed under the addition and scalar multiplication. Both 1), 2) and 3) doesn't contain the zero vector, which if I'm not mistaken exclude the sets from being a subspace, but I don't know how to prove to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I hope i ve understood well your question and here my solution but I am just a student so take it careffully. Moreover I assume that you mean a sub vector space.

1. If we have $x=-z$ and $x=z \Rightarrow -z=x=z \Rightarrow z=-z \Rightarrow z=0 \; and \;  
    x=z=0$.
   So: $U_1= \left \{(x;y;z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: (0;y;0)\right \} $. $0_V \in U_1$ and $\forall u, u' \in U_1 \Rightarrow \alpha u + \beta u' = (0; \alpha y_u + \beta y_{u'}; 0 ) \in U_1$ by definition so $U_1$ is a s.v.s.
2. $U_2 = \left \{(x;y;z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: (x;\frac{3x-7}{2};2x-2)\right \}$ because: $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y+2}{3} \Rightarrow y = \frac{3x-7}{2}$ and $\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{z}{4}  \Rightarrow z = 2x -2 $. Obviously $(0;0;0) \notin U_2$ hence it is not a s.v.s
3. $U_3 = \left \{(x;y;z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: (1)x+y+z = 0 \; and \; (2)x-y+z =1\right \}$ Let check if $0_{\mathbb{R^3}}=(0;0;0)$ is in $U_3$.
   $0_{\mathbb{R^3}}$ verify (1) since: $0+0+0=0$ but does not verify (2). Indeed $0-0+0 = 0 \neq 1 \Rightarrow 0_{\mathbb{R^3}} \notin U_3$ so $U_3$ is not a s.v.s.

I hope my answer is correct.

Comment: I agree for 2) and 3) but for 1) can't "$x$" be any number, why should $x=z=0$ though? 0 is the only value that fulfills the condition $x=-z$ and $x=z$ but what about the rest and also for the closure under multiplication?

Comment: @Techlover If i understood you well you wrotte that $x$ must verifies $x=z$ and $x=-z \rightarrow -x=z$ at the same time so $x=z=-x \Rightarrow x=-x \Rightarrow x =0 $ and as $z=x$ so $z=x=0 \Rightarrow z =0$